# How to generate multiple density plots or one overlay plot with multiple densities with seaborn in a long dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, overlay

I've been trying to do an overlay graph or a multi-plot grid of a filtered data from a pandas dataframe, but I've only been able to generate the plots separately. The code that generates the separated plots is the following:

```
# Get the class counts for all objects
class_counts = get_class_counts(clean_df, 0.4)

# Select the top 5 most common objects
top_5_class_counts = class_counts.head(5)

# Create a new dataframe
df_filtered = df[['image', 'class_name']]

# Merge the class counts dataframe with the dataframe containing the image_file and class_name columns
merged_df = df_filtered.merge(top_5_class_counts, on='class_name')

# Group the data by the class_name column
grouped_df = merged_df.groupby('class_name')

# Iterate over the groups and plot the histograms
for name, group in grouped_df:
    # Count the number of times each image appears in the group and store the results
    image_counts = group.groupby(['image', 'class_name']).size().reset_index(name='count')    
    
    # Create a histogram of the count column using seaborn's displot function
    sns.displot(image_counts, x='count', kind='kde', multiple='stack')
    plt.show()
```

Any help will be appreciate.

A snippet of the merged dataframe:

| image | class_name | class_id | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| berl_000000.png | person | 0 | 1462 |
| berl_000002.png | person | 0 | 1462 |
| berl_000002.png | person | 0 | 1462 |
| berl_000003.png | person | 0 | 1462 |
| berl_000003.png | person | 0 | 1462 |
| zur_000119.png | truck | 7 | 189 |
| zur_000116.png | truck | 7 | 189 |

Comment: Can you share your `merged_df` table? I think you want to use `kdeplot` and `hue='class_name'` instead of iterating across names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Thanks for editing your question. You can accomplish the work in your `for` loop without looping and create a new table which you can then plot from:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

##################
#Create fake data#
##################
num_classes = 8
counts_per_class = 1000
num_images = 100

class_names = np.repeat([f'class_{i+1}' for i in range(num_classes)],counts_per_class)
images = [f'image_{c+1}.png' for c in np.random.randint(0,num_images,num_classes*counts_per_class)]

#this table has a row for each class/image and can have duplicate rows like:
#this is just like your merged_df I think
#   class_name         image
#     class_1       image_10.png
#     class_1       image_11.png
#     class_1       image_11.png
#     class_1       image_12.png
#        ...            ...
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'class_name':class_names,
    'image':images,
})

#Do the work you're doing in your loop all at once w/out a loop
#this table has a unique row per class/image and a new count column
#   class_name         image  count
#      class_1  image_10.png      1
#      class_1  image_11.png      2
#      class_1  image_12.png      1
#        ...            ...
count_df = df.groupby(['class_name','image']).size().reset_index(name='count')

###################################
#Make the overlay displot with hue#
###################################
sns.displot(
    x = 'count',
    hue = 'class_name',
    kind = 'kde',
    data = count_df,
)

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image]

You can achieve the same plot with the for-loop if you want, but the workflow would be (1) create a new empty table, (2) loop through the classes in your loop, appending the per-class table to the new table (3) after looping plot

Comment: I've just tried the code you provide but I just getting one class name in the plot. If I don't do the loop, the count for each group is not performed. I do not know what to do.

Comment: ok I think I know how to solve it, but I'm confused about your `merged_df` example table, where is the `image` column that you use in your loop?

Comment: it was a typo, I've just edited the question, thank you.

Comment: I think I have to do a helper function to retrieve the information that is store in the loop, maybe that way your code would work.

Comment: I've edited my answer and I think it should work for your use case. The main takeaway is to store the loop info into a single table as you've said and then plot only a single time instead of each loop iteration. I don't think your loop is necessary though and can instead be replaced with a single line

Comment: Yes, that's the answer, thank you.

Comment: You might want to use `sns.displot(...., common_norm=False)` to prevent that the curves are scaled down depending on the number of rows belonging to each.